# As3 how to call and use an external class

Tags: actionscript-3, class

I have this cool As3 MP3pitch package, which I got from here: http://blog.andre-michelle.com/2009/pitch-mp3/#more-483

```
package components
{
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.SampleDataEvent;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;

/**
 * @author Andre Michelle (andre.michelle@gmail.com)
 */
public class MP3Pitch 
{
    private const BLOCK_SIZE: int = 3072;

    private var _mp3: Sound;
    private var _sound: Sound;

    private var _target: ByteArray;

    private var _position: Number;
    private var _rate: Number;

    public function MP3Pitch( url: String )
    {
        _target = new ByteArray();

        _mp3 = new Sound();
        _mp3.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, complete );
        _mp3.load( new URLRequest( url ) );

        _position = 0.0;
        _rate = 1.0;

        _sound = new Sound();
        _sound.addEventListener( SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, sampleData );
    }

    public function get rate(): Number
    {
        return _rate;
    }

    public function set rate( value: Number ): void
    {
        if( value < 0.0 )
            value = 0;

        _rate = value;
    }

    private function complete( event: Event ): void
    {
        _sound.play();
    }

    private function sampleData( event: SampleDataEvent ): void
    {
        //-- REUSE INSTEAD OF RECREATION
        _target.position = 0;

        //-- SHORTCUT
        var data: ByteArray = event.data;

        var scaledBlockSize: Number = BLOCK_SIZE * _rate;
        var positionInt: int = _position;
        var alpha: Number = _position - positionInt;

        var positionTargetNum: Number = alpha;
        var positionTargetInt: int = -1;

        //-- COMPUTE NUMBER OF SAMPLES NEED TO PROCESS BLOCK (+2 FOR INTERPOLATION)
        var need: int = Math.ceil( scaledBlockSize ) + 2;

        //-- EXTRACT SAMPLES
        var read: int = _mp3.extract( _target, need, positionInt );

        var n: int = read == need ? BLOCK_SIZE : read / _rate;

        var l0: Number;
        var r0: Number;
        var l1: Number;
        var r1: Number;

        for( var i: int = 0 ; i < n ; ++i )
        {
            //-- AVOID READING EQUAL SAMPLES, IF RATE < 1.0
            if( int( positionTargetNum ) != positionTargetInt )
            {
                positionTargetInt = positionTargetNum;

                //-- SET TARGET READ POSITION
                _target.position = positionTargetInt << 3;

                //-- READ TWO STEREO SAMPLES FOR LINEAR INTERPOLATION
                l0 = _target.readFloat();
                r0 = _target.readFloat();

                l1 = _target.readFloat();
                r1 = _target.readFloat();
            }

            //-- WRITE INTERPOLATED AMPLITUDES INTO STREAM
            data.writeFloat( l0 + alpha * ( l1 - l0 ) );
            data.writeFloat( r0 + alpha * ( r1 - r0 ) );

            //-- INCREASE TARGET POSITION
            positionTargetNum += _rate;

            //-- INCREASE FRACTION AND CLAMP BETWEEN 0 AND 1
            alpha += _rate;
            while( alpha >= 1.0 ) --alpha;
        }

        //-- FILL REST OF STREAM WITH ZEROs
        if( i < BLOCK_SIZE )
        {
            while( i < BLOCK_SIZE )
            {
                data.writeFloat( 0.0 );
                data.writeFloat( 0.0 );

                ++i;
            }
        }

        //-- INCREASE SOUND POSITION
        _position += scaledBlockSize;
    }
}

}
```

How can I include it into my "main" as3 file and use it? I can't just slap it into the same file, since the main file already has it's own package and class.

Essentially what I'm trying to do here is to load a sound file, play it, and change it's pitch in relation to the values what I have already.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a folder with the same name as the package (here `components`) and put this class in it. Then from your main, import this class:

```
import components.MP3Pitch
```

You just have to instanciate this class and use it in your code:

```
var pitcher:MP3Pitch = new MP3Pitch("mymp3.mp3");
pitcher.rate = 2;
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot for a very quick reply. It had to be something as simple as that. Now though, it loads the sound file successfully and plays it for me, but Flash Builder doesn't like the second row: "pitcher.rate = 2;" "Access to undefined property pitcher", even though I declare it immediately above as you did. Additionally when I do write "pitcher." it does give an suggestion of "rate"...Hmm.. How hard can it be.

Comment: Ah. Apparently the "pitcher.rate" has to be inside a function in order to be recognised. Thanks.

Comment: Right, you can't write code outside a function in a class. You can only declare variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
package {

import components.MP3Pitch;

public class Main extends Sprite
{
    public function Main() {
       new MP3Pitch("http://path-to-mp3-file.com/");
    }

}
}
```